# Visual Studio 2012 not exists mfplatf.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, ms-media-foundation, wrl

I want to make an example  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj872764.aspx
When I compile the library c++, I see error:  error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfplatf.lib' 
Where can I find it?

Comment: Perhaps a typo, and it should be `Mfplat.lib`

Comment: It is most likely a typo on the MSDN website like @RomanR. menrtioned. y `Mfplat.lib` first, if that doesn't work download the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 2):

`Mfplat.lib` is part of the Windows SDK available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows//bb980924.aspx), with a list of the headers and libraries included [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And you have more information about the `Windows Media Foundation` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).